# ACPI errors during startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, acpi

I have a dual boot setup Windows/Kubuntu.  When selecting Ubuntu from GRUB, I receive some ACPI errors that flash a couple of times pretty quickly before booting to the desktop. Everything seems to be working fine when booted. Any idea what these errors are or how to fix?

```
[    0.346708] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\SMIB], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-637)
[    0.348709] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP4.WLAN], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
[    0.348714] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND,During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
```